# How to know what eigenvalue corresponds to measurements of individual qubits in a multiqubit system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, linear-algebra, quantum-measurements

I'm working through the book "Introduction to the Theory of Quantum Information Processing" by Bergou and Hillary, and I've encountered a scenario that I'm not sure how to approach. In chapter 3, problem 1, you're essentially supposed to show how a 2 qubit quantum system can violate Wigner's inequality, which is given as

$$
p(a_1=1, b_2=1)+p(a_2=1,b_3=1)\ge p(a_1=1,b_3=1),
$$
where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are some observables, whose results can either be $-1$ or $1$ and are are anticorrelated for for $i=j$ (that is if $a_1$ measures 1, $b_1$ measures -1, and vice versa).

The problem instructs to show this with the operators
$$
a_1=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x,
$$
$$
a_2=\sigma_z, 
$$
$$
a_3=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x,
$$
where $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_x$ are the respective Pauli matrices, and similarly for $b_{1,2,3}$; and the initial state of the system being the bell state
$$
|\Omega_-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_a |1\rangle_b+|1\rangle_a |0\rangle_b).
$$
The general method of approaching this is fairly obvious to me, you just need to take the "combined" operators $a_1b_2, a_2b_3$, and $a_1b_3$ and find the probabilities of getting a 1 for each qubit.

Take $a_1b_2$,
$$
a_1b_2=(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{za}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_{xa})\otimes\sigma_{zb},
$$
which in matrix form (if my understanding is correct) is,
$$
a_1b_2=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -\sqrt{3} \\
 \sqrt{3} & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -\sqrt{3} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which of course has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=1,\lambda_3=-1,\lambda_4=-1$ as expected since we desire those to be the only outcomes. Then I find the the probability of the outcomes in the usual manner, with $|\lambda_n\rangle$ being the eigenstate corresponding to the n-th eigenvalue, the probability is
$$
p(\lambda_n)=|\langle \lambda_n|\Omega_-\rangle|^2
$$

However, my problem is that I'm not familiar with how to determine which eigenvalue/eigenstate corresponds to what outcomes for the individual qubits. I would think that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ correspond to the outcomes where the measurement is the same for both qubits, either $1$ for $-1$ for both qubits, while $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ correspond to the outcomes where they're different, $-1$ for qubit $a$ and $1$ for qubit $b$ or $1$ for $a$ and $-1$ for $b$, but I have no justification for that.

How is this determined? How do I know which eigenstate of an operator in the basis of the full system corresponds to what outcomes for the individual qubits?

Edit: As pointed out in several comments and answers, I transcribed the problem incorrectly from the book, $|\Omega_-\rangle$ should have a minus sign in the expression instead of a plus sign (actually it should also be called $|\Phi_-\rangle$ to match the book's notation). However, at this point, several answers have already been given, and I will have marked one as correct based on the original statement of my post. Thank you to those who realized my mistake and pointed it out.

Comment: Once you have the eigenvalues of a matrix, you can calculate the eigenvector for every eigenvalue - it is a simple set of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns, the components of the eigenvector. The eigenvector will list out exactly what two-qubit state, or superposition of states, is giving that eigenvalue - for example, if the eigenvector is (1,0,0,0), it is the $|00\rangle$ state, which means both qubits needed to be 0, or down.

Comment: Generally you could get an entangled two-qubit state and interpretation will be hard, but here your operator is separable, it acts on both qubits independently, so the eigenstates of the combined operator will also be outer products of the eigenstates of the individual operators. This is another way to interpret the results, by noting which 1-qubit eigenstates outer-product to give a specific 2-qubit eigenstate.

Let me know if you would like me to write this as an answer with a little more math.

Comment: @Green05 That is specifically what I'm looking for. I know one of the eigenvalues/eigenstates MUST correspond to each of the 4 pairs of outcomes for the individual qubits (as those are the only possible real observables), but it isn't obvious to me which one corresponds to the 1,1 outcome which would then tell me the probability of that outcome, which is what the problem says to find. I can provide further context from the book if that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry to comment so late, but you might get better answers at the quantum computing stack exchange:  https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hft I actually posted it there first, got no interaction for a day, and then decided to try also putting it here.

Comment: Are you sure the vector $\Omega_-$ is transcribed correctly? Should it have a relative minus sign rather than plus?

Comment: I wrote up an answer, but I don't think the $\Omega_-$ state, as currently written in this question, can be used to show the violation of the inequality. This is explained more in my answer.

Comment: @YaGoiRoot just checked directly in the book, and the state you wrote is incorrect. It should be $\Omega_- = 1/\sqrt{2}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$. But you have two answers that, regarding the choice of state, illustrate how this type of calculation can be done.

Comment: @Alex yes you are correct, I had a typo in my original post. I'll make an edit acknowledging that but I'll select an answer in regards to the original state of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm working through the book "Introduction to the Theory of Quantum Information Processing" by Bergou and Hillary, and I've encountered a scenario that I'm not sure how to approach. In chapter 3, problem 1, you're essentially supposed to show how a 2 qubit quantum system can violate Wigner's inequality, which is given as
>
> $$
> p(a_1=1, b_2=1)+p(a_2=1,b_3=1)\ge p(a_1=1,b_3=1),
> $$
> where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are some observables, whose results can either be $-1$ or $1$ and are are anticorrelated for for $i=j$ (that is if $a_1$ measures 1, $b_1$ measures -1, and vice versa).

> The problem instructs to show this with the operators
> $$
> a_1=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x,
> $$
> $$
> a_2=\sigma_z, 
> $$
> $$
> a_3=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x,
> $$
> where $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_x$ are the respective Pauli matrices, and similarly for $b_{1,2,3}$; and the initial state of the system being the bell state
> $$
> |\Omega_-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_a |1\rangle_b+|1\rangle_a |0\rangle_b).
> $$

As I mentioned in the comments, I think the above-quoted expression for $\Omega_-$ is the wrong state to use to show a violation of the Wigner inequality. I think this might be a transcription error by OP, or an erratum in the textbook.

To avoid confusion, I will use the notation:
$$
|\Psi_{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle \pm |1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle\right)\;,
$$
where, with OP's current notation, $\Omega_- \equiv \Psi_+$, but I think this might be a typo/error in the textbook or a transcription error, for reasons that will be clarified presently.

I find:
$$
p(a_1 = 1, b_2 = 1)_{\pm} = \frac{1}{8}
$$
$$
p(a_2 = 1, b_3 = 1)_{\pm} = \frac{1}{8}
$$
$$
p(a_1 = 1, b_3 = 1)_{\pm} = \left\{\begin{matrix}0\\\frac{3}{8}\end{matrix}\right\}\;,
$$
where the upper entry in the expression above is for initial state $|\Psi_+\rangle$ and the lower is for initial state $|\Psi_-\rangle$.

If we are looking for an initial state that shows a **violation** of the Wigner inequality, then we seemingly want to look at $|\Psi_-\rangle$, not $|\Psi_+\rangle$ (or we want to choose different measurements).

---

> However, my problem is that I'm not familiar with how to determine which eigenvalue/eigenstate corresponds to what outcomes for the individual qubits. I would think that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ correspond to the outcomes where the measurement is the same for both qubits, either $1$ for $-1$ for both qubits, while $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ correspond to the outcomes where they're different, $-1$ for qubit $a$ and $1$ for qubit $b$ or $1$ for $a$ and $-1$ for $b$, but I have no justification for that.
>
> How is this determined? How do I know which eigenstate of an operator in the basis of the full system corresponds to what outcomes for the individual qubits?

You really don't want to look at eigenstates of $a_1 b_2$, since, as you noted, there are two eigenvectors with eigenvalue +1. *One* of those two eigenvectors
$$
|v\rangle = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{3}/2\\
0\\
1/2\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\right)
\otimes|0\rangle\;,
$$
is the state of interest, and the other is the state with $a_1$ eigenvalue $-1$ and $b_2$ eigenvalue $-1$ (which still gives an $a_1b_2$ eigenvalue +1).

Since the problem asks you about individual measurements of each of the "a" and "b" qubits, it is best to just keep working with direct product representations based on the individual qubit operators $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$.

The other states of interest are (for $a_2$ +1 and $b_3$ +1):
$$
|w\rangle =|0\rangle\otimes\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle - \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\right) 
$$
and (for $a_1$ +1 and $b_3$ +1)
$$
|u\rangle = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\right)\otimes\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle - \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\right)\;.
$$

And, as already written with less context above:
$$
p_{\pm}(a_1=1,b_2=1)= |\langle v|\Psi_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{8}
$$
$$
p_{\pm}(a_2=1,b_3=1)= |\langle w|\Psi_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{8}
$$
$$
p_{\pm}(a_1=1,b_3=1)= |\langle u|\Psi_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = \left\{\begin{matrix}0\\\frac{3}{8}\end{matrix}\right\}
$$

Comment: Yes, I had a typo copying the problem from the book, thank you for realizing this. I'll make an edit to the original post acknowledging this.

Comment: I have selected this answer as it specifically addresses the question of knowing which eigenvector of the operator corresponds to the outcome whose probability I was concerned with, which was the key part in my understanding that I was lacking.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the state

$$\Omega_- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$$

you will find that there is **NO** violation. Let me show this. Note that the approach I will use for solving this problem can be applied to any choice of state, and this ultimately answers your question.

Given that Alice and Bob are set to measure different operators, each having two outcomes (+1 and -1), the simplest method to determine the probability for each measurement outcome is to first identify the eigenvectors corresponding to each operator individually. After this, one can construct the respective probability distributions. Here's how this can be done:

Let's define a general measurement operator $m_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, where $m$ stands for $a$ (Alice) or $b$ (Bob).

**Measurement operator:** $m_1 = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_z + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x$

It can be shown that the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $+1$ is

$$|m^{+}_1\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle.$$

**Measurement operator:** $m_2 = \sigma_z$

This one's straightforward! Since it is already diagonal in the computational basis, the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue is just:
$$|m_2^{+}\rangle = |0\rangle$$

**Measurement operator:** $m_3 = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_z - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sigma_x.$

In a manner analogous to $m_1$, he eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $+1$ for this operator is:

$$|m^{+}_3\rangle = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle.$$

Now, here's the fun part: when you're ready to crunch out those probabilities, you've got options! You can either go with the matrix representation or stick with our good ol' ket-bra notation.

**ket-bra notation:**

$$p(a_1=1, b_2=1)=|\langle a^{+}_1 b^{+}_2|\Omega_1\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{8}$$
$$p(a_2=1, b_3=1)=|\langle a^{+}_2 b^{+}_3|\Omega_1\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{8}$$
$$p(a_1=1, b_3=1)=|\langle a^{+}_1 b^{+}_3|\Omega_1\rangle|^2 = 0$$
and, in fact, there is **no** violation as
$$p(a_1=1, b_2=1)+p(a_2=1, b_3=1) > p(a_1=1, b_3=1)$$.

However, if you consider the other Bell-state

$$|\Psi_-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle),$$

then we see a violation since

$$p(a_1=1, b_3=1)=\operatorname{tr}(M\rho M^{\dagger}) = \frac{3}{8}.$$

Let me just tell you how you can carried out the calculations using a matrix notation:

**Matrix notation:**

First, note that our state is given by:

$$\rho:= |\Psi_-\rangle \langle \Psi_-| = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Now, defining the following measurement operator

$$M_1:=|a^{+}_1\rangle\langle a^{+}_1|\otimes|b^{+}_2\rangle\langle b^{+}_2| =\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

one can show that

$$p(a_1=1, b_2=1)=\operatorname{tr}(M\rho M^{\dagger}) = \frac{1}{8}.$$

The other matrices can be similarly reconstructed.

Comment: You've introduced a notation $\Omega_1$ rather than $\Omega_-$, which seemingly must be different from OP's $\Omega_-$. If you use OP's $\Omega_-$ state, you find $|\langle a^{+}_1 b^{+}_3|\Omega_-\rangle|^2 = 0 \neq \frac{3}{8}$. I think OP might have a typo. But anyways, if you use your $\rho$ (which is based on OP's $\Omega_-$), it seem that you will actually find $tr(M_3\rho M_3^\dagger)=0$. (Where $M_3:=|a^{+}_1\rangle\langle a^{+}_1|\otimes|b^{+}_3\rangle\langle b^{+}_3| $).

Comment: Indeed it was a typo from my side. I got confused by his notation and thought he was assuming the other Bell state.

Comment: After your latest edit, I think you need to update your expression on the RHS of your equation for $\rho$. Since you have updated your $\Omega_-$, he $\rho$ should have two $1/2$ entries and two $-1/2$ entries. (Not all 1/2)